# JS script in django html template

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, scroll, django-templates

I want to have infinity scroll of my posts. Below are my .html file and script. (I have set up static etc correct). How can I place JS script between `<div id="test">` in html?
**my django .html:**

```
{% block content %}
  <div id="test">
  {% for post in posts %}
    {{post.title}} | {{post.text}}        
  {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**JS code:**

```
$(window).scroll(function()
{
    if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())
    {
          $("#test") //HERE SUPPOSED TO BE MY CODE is #test ok?
    }
});
```

So how can I place JS code? `{% block content %}` and `{% endblock %}` must be inside JS script. How to do this :(

Comment: How about `script tag`?? <script type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Doesnt work, tried.

Comment: your jquery must be above this part of the code, where do you call the jquery package??

Comment: In header I got CDN to jquery/js
So is ($test) in right place? That will make my posts scroll going infinity? Cos so far it doesnt work. And js code was above.

Comment: add `console.log('something')` or `alert('something')` to see if this script has triggered

Comment: I suggest that you use a `file.js` to do this... Or in order to have some Django variables, add js codes inside a `script tag` right in the same template, by using for instance: `{% block scripts%} <script></script> {% endblock %}`

Comment: I added alert() and it appears only when I scroll down to very bottom of page, so maybe script will not load posts? Im confused, JS is not my strong advantage, I can only use python :(

Comment: what did you end up doing? did it work?

Comment: Nope, still waiting for help. On other hand, can I use comparision inside {%%} for example I want to check type of post "URGENT", but I cannot perform: {% if post.type == "URGENT" %} because it says "Could not parse the remainder ==".

Comment: yes you can, but the `==`  should not be tight to the word "URGENT", keep them isolated